# How to get $LINES and $COLUMNS from a Qt console application?

Tags: c++, qt, environment-variables, posix, qprocess

When I run my application, it is usually in a Terminal. I would like to be able to grab COLUMNS and LINES, such as what you would find in:

```
echo $LINES
```

however, looking in `QProcess::systemEnvironment()`, I can not find the environment variable as it has not been explicitly set.

How can I get this in Qt?

Comment: QByteArray qgetenv ( const char * varName ) ?

Comment: @AndreySemenov Ill give it a shot